# How to listen to port 443 on BurpSuite

Tags: proxy

I'm trying to set up an invisible proxy (using [this guide](https://support.portswigger.net/customer/portal/articles/2899081-using-burp-s-invisible-proxy-settings-to-test-a-non-proxy-aware-thick-client-application)). At some point in the guide it is said that I have to listen to the following interface:

```
127.0.0.1:443
```

Once set up, I'm not able to select the interface *(tick the Running box)*:

[image]

That beeing said I also get the following error message in the *Event Log*:

[image]

Am I doing something wrong in setting up this invisible proxy? if not how can I listen to this port?

What I'm using:

- an iMac running macOS Mojave (on which I'm having an admin account)
- [BurpSuite 2.1.02](http://releases.portswigger.net/2019/07/professional-community-edition-2102.html)

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: What does the output of `lsof -i 443` tell you?

Comment: @mhr Thanks for your quick reply, I get the following output when running the command: https://imgur.com/a/utr615X

Comment: Sorry, wrong syntax! Try `lsof -i :443` to get anything on port `443` - or the one that @Luc suggested.

Comment: While this post is about Burp Suite, a security program, the question is about listening on port 443, which is program-independent and has nothing to do with "[protecting assets from threats and vulnerabilities](https://security.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)". SuperUser is the site for general software questions, so I have voted to move the question there.

Answer (score 4):

Port `443` is a privileged port. You are probably not running Burp Suite as root (which I would generally also not recommend from a security perspective), so it will not be able to bind to that port.

There should be a message about this in the error log of Burp Suite. I think it's under Dashboard on the bottom left these days (used to be in Help, if I remember correctly, maybe it's still there if you're on Burp 1.x).

Unless Burp Suite can drop privileges (not as far as I know), the best solution would be to proxy traffic from port 443 to Burp on another port, such as 8443. Or do it the quick and dirty way with `sudo BurpSuiteCommunity` :)

It could also be that port `443` is already in use by another application. On macOS, this can be detected using `lsof -i -P | grep -i "listen"` ([source](https://benohead.com/mac-netstat-list-ports-programs/)).

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply so if Traffic from port 443 to 8443 should I also modify the host file once again? currently I just added `127.0.0.1    example.com` to my host file.

Comment: @Fozoro I don't know exactly about your setup and what your hosts file should be. If you added `127.0.0.1 example.com` before to make the traffic go to your machine, then you should still do that: your proxy will still be on your machine, just that some other program (a much simpler program with hopefully less attack surface so that it can more safely run as root, or perhaps it can drop privileges after binding to the port) will copy the traffic from 443 to 8443. Then Burp listens at 8443 for the traffic and you continue from there. (Or, of course, run Burp Suite as root.)

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! Would you able to recommend any kind of software that I should use for such a task. Many thanks in advance

Comment: @Fozoro I use socat to terminate TLS (i.e. turn https into http traffic), but I don't know if that is what you want, or if socat can forward the TLS traffic without decrypting it. There are probably better tools (much simpler than socat, because all you want is a traffic forward, not TLS termination). You'll have to look if socat works for you or search for something that better suits your needs. Hope this helped!

Answer (score 0):

AFAICT you cant run the native application as root (at least I could not figure it out). You need to drop into a root shell, then run the JAR from there. Once running as root, then you can run the Burp jar and use privileged ports without an issue.